# how to load a UIView on button click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have Seprate `UIView` which i am using in `UIViewController` it initially loads but i want that when that is loaded and I again click on the button then it should reload because it has graph creation method which draws graph when view loaded

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
  #import "ECGraph.h"
  #import "ECGraphItem.h"
  #import "CereniaAppDelegate.h"
  @class GraphsViewController;
  @interface Display : UIView {

NSArray *percentages;
CereniaAppDelegate*appDelegate;
}
  @property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray*percentages;

  -(void) setPercentageArray:(NSArray*) array;
  @end
```

Implementation files

```
 #import "Display.h"
 #import "ECGraph.h"
 #import "CereniaAppDelegate.h"
 @implementation Display
 @synthesize percentages;
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
 self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
 if (self) {
  }
 return self;
 }

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

 CGContextRef _context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


 ECGraph *graph = [[ECGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70,-70,800,200) withContext:
                  _context isPortrait:NO];

    appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


ECGraphItem *item1 = [[ECGraphItem alloc] init];

ECGraphItem *item2 = [[ECGraphItem alloc] init];    

ECGraphItem *item3 = [[ECGraphItem alloc] init];
    item1.isPercentage = YES;

int value=(int)roundf(appDelegate.graphValueOne);
item1.yValue=value;
item1.width = 70;
item1.name = @"Unvaccinated horse"; 

int value1=(int)roundf(appDelegate.graphValueTwo);

item2.isPercentage = YES;
item2.yValue=value1;
item2.width = 70; 

item2.name = @"Annually Vaccinated horse";

int value3=(int)roundf(appDelegate.graphValueThree);
item3.isPercentage = YES;
item3.yValue=value3;

item3.width = 70;
item3.name = @"Semi-Annually vaccinated horse";






NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:item1,item2,item3,nil];
[graph setXaxisTitle:@""];
[graph setYaxisTitle:@"Risk"];
[graph setDelegate:self];
[graph setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[graph drawHistogramWithItems:items lineWidth:2 color:[UIColor blackColor]];


    }
  -(void) setPercentageArray:(NSArray*) array


    {


percentages = array;


NSString*test=[percentages objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(test);


     }



- (void)dealloc {
   [super dealloc];
    }

   @end
```

Comment: hide the uview first and unhide it again mybe ... or allocate it ...

Comment: @Gill only adding & removing the UIView does not reloads it containts. You must needs to allocate & add it again.

Comment: @Girish yes you right can you tell me how re allocate and add it after once it is loaded

Comment: @Girish i wrote allocate there smewhere read again plz :)

Comment: Create object of that view in .h file & check existence of that view, if exists then release else allocate new object & add it. Which may solves your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get any view to redraw with

```
[view setNeedsDisplay];
```

So on your refresh button you would update the data used by the Display class and then setNeedsDisplay.

Comment: where to call this method after updating data

Comment: You would probably habe an IBAction in your view controller linked with the reload button. Put it there.

Comment: @interface RiskViewController : UIViewController {

 
 
 Display*display;
 
this is the view controller where i am using that view so how to redraw it again over here

Comment: yes i have put it over there but it is not creating the view again

Comment: After updating the data in display: [display setNeedsDisplay]